# Sum of list in dictionary with same key

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a database in mongo and i want to sum some values here my database data:

```
user = {

    'name':'john',
    'surname':'john',
    'basket':[{"name":"second","price":5},{"name":"first","price":5}]
  
}
```

I this database i want to get the sum of prices. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single user:

`sum(x['price'] for x in user['basket'])`